# mysql select filtered count for field along with total rows in table for same field

Tags: mysql

I have a table with customers and stores. Stores represents the places in which they have purchased something from me. I want to count how many times they have bought something from each store along with the total count of times they've purchased something from any store.

Sample Table called PURCHASE:

```
Customer    Store
ABC         Store 1
ABC         Store 2
ABC         Store 2
ABC         Store 3
ABC         Store 3
ABC         Store 4
ABC         Store 4
ABC         Store 4
```

The results I want:

```
Customer    Store       Count   Total
ABC         Store 1       1       8
ABC         Store 2       2       8
ABC         Store 3       2       8
ABC         Store 4       3       8
```

I tried something like this but it took a long time as there are over 40k records:

```
SELECT a.customer, store, count(a.customer) AS thisstore
FROM PURCHASE a 
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT COUNT(customer) AS totalsales,customer 
    FROM PURCHASE 
    GROUP BY customer) b 
ON b.customer=N.customer GROUP BY a.customer;
```

If anyone knows of a better way to do this please let me know - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the output you asked for and should be faster provided you have an index on `PURCHASE.customer` :

```
SELECT a.customer, a.store, count(*) AS thisstore
, (select count(*) from PURCHASE b where b.customer=a.customer) as total
FROM PURCHASE a 
GROUP BY a.customer,a.store
```

Comment: tomb - thanks so much for your help. I totally missed creating the index which was huge. Really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries man. Would you be able to upvote and approve the answer so I get the reputation please?